# Excel: reference to a range, not “name” in formula

Tags: excel, reference

Assuming the range A1:M10 in sheet 1, can I get the contents of the range defined in sheet 1 in the cell e.g. B2 in sheet 2? I mean the starting cell in sheet 2 is B2, then the range following has the contents of the range defined in sheet 1. The situation is that main calculation (very in detail) is done in sheet 1. In sheet 2, it only outputs the key or final results. Every time when the main sheet is changed, the contents in sheet 2 changes accordingly.

Comment: Seems like a simple formula ?  I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: In cell B2 Sheet2, simply use `='Sheetname'!A1` (replace `Sheetname` with the appropriate worksheet name). Formulae are dynamic in Excel, so it will change accordingly when you copy the formula across. That should work unless you have more you haven't said that makes it more complex...